# Random access alternative to named pipes

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

Is there a way to create a "file" (i.e. some point in the file system) that can then be opened by any program as a regular file, but reading/writing to it will go to a program instead of to disk? Named pipe seems to meet all the requirements, except it only allows serial file access.

I am interested currently in *nix type systems, but would be curious to hear of such a system on any OS/file system.

Comment: To answer this question would require more information. As noted below, mmap () MIGHT worker but only if you had a fixed file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an implementation:

demon.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

void map_file(const char *f) {
    int fd = open(f, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("fd open error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    char *addr = (char *)mmap(NULL, 10, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
        addr[i] = '0' + i;
    }
    while (1) {
        for (i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
            if (addr[i] != '0' + i) {
                printf("addr[%d]: %c\n", i, addr[i]);
            }
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    map_file("/dev/mem");
    return 0;
 }
```

cli.c:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    const char *f = "/dev/mem";
    int fd = open(f, O_RDWR, 0666);
    assert(fd >= 0); 
    lseek(fd, rand() % 10, SEEK_SET);
    write(fd, "X", 1); 
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

we map 10 bytes memory from "/dev/mem" to our demon program. cli open this file as a regular file, and write a byte in random address. Of course, you can map any other file instead of /dev/mem, but you need to 'alloc' some byte from regular file before mmap. eg:

```
fd = open("/path/to/myfile", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);
write(fd, "0123456789", 10);   // 'allocate' 10 bytes from regular file
addr = (char *)mmap(NULL, 10, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use mmap to create a share memory, a backend program hold this memory. Other program can open this 'file' and random read/write it to the backend program.

I haven't tried but I think it can work!

Answer (score 0):

I think the asker is referring to the special case where the program that is providing the file, hooks into all accesses by the program using/accessing/opening the file, because otherwise the provider-program would have no control over what the user-program is reading/writing when and where. In such a case the provider-program could simply open a standard file in a mode that allows concurrent reads/writes by any other program.

In the hook-case, research the following solutions: libFUSE, BUSE, python-fuse, scriptfs, NBD, NBDkit.